# How to solve error 422 with mongoose and vue

Tags: api, vue.js, express, mongoose, axios

I'm using an API with express and mongoose to add events to my database but I have an error 422 with axios but not with Postman.

I'm using a Vue3 Project by the way

The error is : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Here is my API Code :

```
//Degustations.model.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const degustationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    places: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    places_left: {
      type: Number,
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    image:{
        type: String,
    },
    ref:{
      type: String,
  }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
)

const Degustations = mongoose.model('degustation', degustationsSchema)

module.exports = {
  Degustations
}
```

```
// Degustations.ctrl.js

const Degustations = require('../models/degustations.model').Degustations
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.withCredentials = true

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  await Degustations
    .create(req.value.body)
    .then((inserted) => {
      console.log('✅ Success to add:', inserted._id)
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: `content ${result._id} created`,
        result: inserted,
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(' Error to add:', err)
      if (err.code === 11000) {
        res
          .status(409)
          .json({ message: 'this address email already existing' })
      } else if (
        err.errors &&
        Object.keys(err.errors).length > 0 &&
        err.name === 'ValidationError'
      ) {
        res.status(422).json({ message: err.message })
      } else {
        res.status(500).json(err)
      }
    })
}

  function findAll(req, res) {
    return Degustations.find()
      .exec()
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.json(result)
        } else {
          res.status(202).json({ message: 'no users available' })
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json(err)
      })
  }

  function deleteById(req, res) {
    // Récupération de l'id
    const id = req.params.id
  
    // Requête Mongoose - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove
    return Content.findByIdAndRemove({ _id: id })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          // Présence d'un objet de données
          res.json({ message: `user ${id} deleted` })
        } else {
          // Ligne non existante
          res.status(404).json({ message: `degustation ${id} not found` })
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json(err)
      })
  }

module.exports = {
    saveOne,
    findAll,
    deleteById,
}
```

And here is my axios test request with which I have the error :

```
async addEvent() {
      this.axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/degustations", {
        data: {
          title: "eazeazea",
          description: "Venez profitez de ce truc là ouais",
          price: "15",
          places: "12",
          date: "2000-07-05T00:00:00.000Z",
          image: "",
          places_left: "8",
          ref: "prod_Jq4Z4YfZeMtOJi",
        },
      }).then((response) => console.log(response));
    }
```

But here is the generated code with postman whihch is not working too but the simple postman request is working :

```
var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require('qs');
var data = qs.stringify({
  'title': 'eazeazea',
  'description': 'Venez profitez de ce truc là ouais',
  'price': '15',
  'places': '12',
  'date': '2000-07-05',
  'image': '',
  'places_left': '8',
  'ref': 'prod_Jq4Z4YfZeMtOJi' 
});
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/degustations',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Do someone have any idea on how to solve this error ?

Here are my route codes :

```
// index.routes.js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

// Endpoint des utilisateurs
router.use('/api/v1/content', require('./content.routes'))
router.use('/api/v1/users', require('./users.routes'))
router.use('/api/v1/degustations', require('./degustations.routes'))

module.exports = router

//Degustations.routes.js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Degustations = require('../controllers/degustations.ctrl')
const m = require('../helpers/middlewares')

router.post('/', Degustations.saveOne);
router.get('/', Degustations.findAll);


module.exports = router
```

Comment: can you provide us the code of your route?

Comment: It's done you have my 2 routes codes

Comment: wow I see. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1- To pass some function in your routes, the best way is use module.exports in controller function.

2- And I think you can create async/await function.

3- Otherwise i have change function to mongoose create,
to simplify things. Please provide us some update.

4- Read more about export Statements here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Take a look in code bellow:

```js
       module.exports = {
       async insert (req, res, next) => {
        await Degustations
          .create(req.value.body)
          .then((inserted) => {
            console.log('✅ Success to add:', inserted._id)
            return res.status(201).json({
              message: `content ${result._id} created`,
              result: inserted,
            })
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(' Error to add:', err)
            if (err.code === 11000) {
              res
                .status(409)
                .json({ message: 'this address email already existing' })
            } else if (
              err.errors &&
              Object.keys(err.errors).length > 0 &&
              err.name === 'ValidationError'
            ) {
              res.status(422).json({ message: err.message })
            } else {
              res.status(500).json(err)
            }
          })
      },
      async findAll() {
        // ... your code here ... 
      },
      async deleteById() {
        // ... your code here ... 
      },
    }

    // to import you can use 
    const {insert, findAll, deleteById} = require('../controllers/degustations.ctrl')
    // OR
    const degustations  = require('../controllers/degustations.ctrl')
    degustations.insert()
    degustations.findAll()
    degustations.deleteById()
```

Comment: please, add console.log in catch statement to get the error message in console as updated code above.

Comment: The problem comes from my axios request. I deleted all my required: true from my model and a new line in my DB is added without any value as the title or something else.

Comment: I have other functions in my degustations.ctrl.js. I updated my first question with the full code

Comment: take a look again?